# App não aparece no emulador

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou criando um app no Android Studio, estou usando o emulador Genymotion, está tudo rodando normal, só que ele não executa o app e nem aparece o ícone no emulador.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mkh5.png)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
inserir a descrição da imagem aqui

inserir a descrição da imagem aqui
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ja conferiu na bandeja de aplicativos?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam o nome do meu app é ComidadiBoteco já procurei na bandeja e só tem os app antigos que fiz.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam será que tem alguma coisa haver com android studio 3.0, ele ta pedindo pra baixar a nova versão.

Comment: Já experimentou com o emulador do Android Studio ? Nos dias de hoje esse seria preferível ao Genymotion

Comment: @Isac tentei também, mas a mesma coisa do genymotion

Comment: Não recomendo a atualização do android studio, to vendo muita gente, inclusive aqui na comunidade, que está tendo problemas depois da atualização, incluindo os aplicativos que estavam funcionando normalmente antes

Answer (score 1):

Opa beleza :)
Já instalou o plugin do Genymotion no Android Studio?

`File` > `Settings` > `Plugins` > `Browse repositories...` > Pesquise por `Genymotion` e o instale

[Mais informações](https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/)